# Multiple Angular8 application in a web page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm working on an application in which 2 separate Angular8 application is getting loaded within same web page. Now from a help of another post I found a solution to load them like following

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libraries/runtime.bundle.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libraries/polyfills-es5.bundle.js" nomodule ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libraries/polyfills.bundle.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libraries/scripts.bundle.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libraries/main.bundle.js"></script>

<script>delete window.webpackJsonp</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/runtime.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/polyfills-es5.bundle.js" nomodule></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Above thing is running perfectly in chrome and firefox but in IE 11 I'm having the famous ZoneJS error and only one of the application is getting loaded. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can you try with having only one polyfills adn pollfills-es5 bundle

Comment: yes I tried by removing all defer keyword and disabling the 2nd polyfills-es5.bundle.js file which will do the job for IE but unfortunately I can't remove the defer as they are getting settled with angular build.